# Pip to upgrade cv2

Tags: python, opencv, pip, installation, upgrade

Python2, I have old version of cv2, 3.1.0.

I did pip upgrade by using

```
pip install opencv-python==4.0.0.21,
```

It says:

```
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.0.0.21
```

But when I check its version again,

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

It still says it’s “3.1.0”.

What went wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux, then try :

sudo pip install opencv-python==4.0.0.21

Make sure the previous version is uninstalled. Commonly cv2.pyd file in (search in Python27 folder) should be removed if pip uninstall does not work. I recommend using latest version:

sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30

And if you are on windows then remove sudo. I hope this may help.

Comment: Alright no problem, please tell me your OS? And also use these commands in python to find out the location of your Python path: import os, then import sys, and os.path.dirname(sys.executable) to show the location of your python. It seems like the pip you use to install is pointing towards a different version of Python.

Comment: You are welcome. I assume D:\Python27 is the path shown when you used os.path.dirname. If this is the case, then go to path D:\Python27\Scripts and from there use pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30.

Comment: Good so go to D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cv2 and check the cv2.cp(version)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203718/discussion-between-azhar-hussain-and-mark-k).

Comment: Hi Mark, is the problem resolved?
If not resolved then go to D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cv2 and in cv2 folder delete all
and then try to import cv2 in a new terminal window
It should now give error instead of 3.1.0
Then unistall pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
and then
again install
by adding a -U option
pip install -U opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
before checking version open a new terminal from outside python directory
and check the version!

Comment: The version 3.1.0 is inside cv2, please confirm that and by using the way above manually delete it.

Comment: thank you for your patience, time and efforts in helping me solving this problem. You are one of those who make this world beautiful. All the best!